# Is it possible to work with extended events (Sql server Extended events ) in Java code?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, extended-events

I have one question. Can I work with extended events in Java code? Run sessions and analyze results. Is there a specific api or interface to do this?

Comment: What does the SQL Server documentation say?

Answer (score 0):

You are using XE trough T-SQL, like running/stopping sessions with [ALTER EVENT SESSION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-event-session-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
ALTER EVENT SESSION test_session ON SERVER STATE = start;
```

And reading the events e.g. from [Ring Buffer Target](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/ring-buffer-target?view=sql-server-2014):

```
SELECT name, target_name, CAST(xet.target_data AS xml)  
FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets AS xet  
JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions AS xe  
   ON (xe.address = xet.event_session_address)  
WHERE xe.name = 'session_name'
```

The result XML [can be processed in the SQL Server](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/01/query-extended-events-target-xml/), or you can process in in your Java code.

So the specific API you are looking for is Transact-SQL.